# Is there currently any way to center the hint of a multi-line TextField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a TextField that can hold multi-line input, pretty much simulating a TextArea since flutter doesn't have those.

The problem I'm encountering is that the hint text isn't vertically centered, even though the prefixIcon is.

```dart
Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: displayWidth(context) * 0.05),
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        height: displayHeight(context) * 0.28,
        width: displayWidth(context) * 0.75,
        decoration: roundedShadowDecoration(context: context, color: secondaryRed(), size: 0.015),
        child: TextField(
          maxLines: 7,
          cursorColor: Colors.white,
          style: GoogleFonts.notoSans(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.04),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.font_download,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: displayWidth(context) * 0.065,
            ),
            hintText: "A TextField Hint",
            hintStyle: GoogleFonts.notoSans(
                color: Colors.white54, fontSize: displayWidth(context) * 0.035),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Is there currently any way to vertically center the hint text in a multi-line TextField?

Comment: You can use the `textAlignVertical` property of the `TextField` @SCcode

Comment: @TimilehinJegede I've tried that, by setting 'textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center', but it doesn't work. There is no difference.

Comment: Hello @SCcode  you can use  textAlign: TextAlign.center property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from adding content padding to manually place the hint text as @hisam suggested, you could make the TextField expand as you type, like so:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      width: 200,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.font_download),
          const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              minLines: 1,
              maxLines: 7,
              cursorColor: Colors.white,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                isDense: true,
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: "A TextField Hint",
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this doesn't specifically answer the question, I'm going to mark it as the answer since it seems to be the best way to go. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the hint text in the middle of multi-line TextField, the only way is to add padding into it.

```
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Enter Something", 
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(150.0), // You can use EdgeInsets.only() to add padding from top and/or bottom. But it will affect your TextField
    ),
  ),
```

**NOTICE** Applying padding in that way will cause your multi-line TextField will be useless. Why? Because the input text will start from the middle of the TextField. So the area for the text input will also be shrunk. And also create a bad User Experience (UX) for the user (at least that's my opinion).

I really don't recommend to center your hint text.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `hintText` multiline like..

```
hintText: "\n\n\nA TextField Hint\n\n\n",
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an appropriate solution as the `cursor` still starts from the top and not where the `hintText` is manually placed.

Comment: Agree. Might not be the best or complete solution. Clearly not an ideal way. A hacky one. There should be an intrinsic way to achieve this with some property of the `TextField` itself. But if there isn't any at the moment, this at least centers the `hintText` and that is also what the question asked for.